# Factor every element of list in python, then append factors to sub-arrays in another array

Tags: python, arrays, append, factors

My goal here is to factor *every single element* of lists firsted and secondeded, append all the factors to sublists pqnum and pqnum3 which will then be appended to the main lists pqnum2(for firsted factors) and pqnum4(for secondeded factors) respectively. Also, firsted and secondeded can be appended by the user (not shown). Below is the code:

```
#Define appendable lists
pqnum = []
pqnum2 = []
pqnum3 = []
pqnum4 = []

#While loop counters
fib = 1
sib = 1

#lists to be factored (may be appended by user)
firsted = [24, -1, 1, 0, -800, 2, 6]
secondeded = [2, -1, 1, 1, 30, 11, 5]

#factor firsted
for index in range(0,len(firsted)-1):
    x = firsted[index]
    while fib<=x:
        if x%fib == 0:
            pqnum.append(fib)
            pqnum.append(-fib)
        fib = fib + 1
    pqnum2.append(pqnum)
print pqnum2

#factor seconded
for index in range(0,len(secondeded)-1):
    while sib<=secondeded[index]:
        if secondeded[index]%sib == 0:
            pqnum3.append(sib)
            pqnum3.append(-sib)
        sib = sib + 1
    pqnum4.append(pqnum3)
print pqnum4
```

The expected output is:

```
[[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1], [1, -1], [0], [all of the factors of -800, positive or negative], [1, -1, 2, -2], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3]]

[[1, -1, 2, -2], [1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 11, -11], [1,-1,5,-5]]
```

But the output that comes out from the code is:

```
[[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24]]

[[1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30], [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 5, -5, 6, -6, 10, -10, 15, -15, 30, -30]]
```

I have been thinking about it for days. I can't seem to find out why. Help, please.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't resetting any of your variables.

After you traverse your `while fib<=x:` loop the first time, `fib = 24` and `pqnum = [1, -1, 2, -2, 3, -3, 4, -4, 6, -6, 8, -8, 12, -12, 24, -24]`.  When you reach that loop the second time, those values haven't changed, so the comparison `fib<=x` immediately fails, since `24 < -1` is false, and the same array `pqnum` is appended to `pqnum2`.

Once you fix this, you would notice that your list of factors of `-1` would be empty, because  the comparison `fib<=x` would still evaluate to false as `1 < -1` is false.  Based on your logic, I would use an absolute value for populating `x`.  This leads to:

```
#factor firsted
for index in range(0,len(firsted)-1):
    x = abs(firsted[index])
    fib = 1
    pqnum = []
    while fib<=x:
        if x%fib == 0:
            pqnum.append(fib)
            pqnum.append(-fib)
        fib = fib + 1
    pqnum2.append(pqnum)
print pqnum2
```